# When i try to display the count value of one column it counts the no. of arrays stored in a single cell of the same row on the same table

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-5, count, subquery

I have written the following function to display a table consisting of 
recipe name, description, cusine , ........ ..., ingredients AND LIKES.
Everything works fine but the likes column doesnot show the no. of likes bu instead sows the no. of ingredients of the recipe

```
 public function rec(){
              $ing = inglist::all();
              $rcusine=recipecusine::all();
              $rtype=recipetype::all();
              $rec = DB::table('recipe_list')
               ->select('recipe_list.recipe_id','recipe_list.Recipe_name',
                 'recipe_list.Recipe_desc','recipe_list.Recipe_duration',
                DB::raw('group_concat(ing_list.Ing_name separator ",") as recipe_ingredients'),
                'recipe_cusine.Cusine_name', 'recipe_type.Recipe_type_name','recipe_list.image',
                DB::raw('count(likerecipes.likecount) as likes'))
                            ->join('recipe_inglist', 'recipe_list.recipe_id','=','recipe_inglist.Recipe_id')
                            ->join('ing_list', 'recipe_inglist.Ing_id','=','ing_list.ing_id')
                            ->join('recipe_cusine', 'recipe_list.Recipe_cusine_id','=','recipe_cusine.cusine_id')
                            ->join('recipe_type', 'recipe_list.Recipe_type_id','=','recipe_type.Recipe_typeID')
                            ->join( 'likerecipes', 'recipe_list.recipe_id', '=', 'likerecipes.recipe_id')
                            ->where('recipe_list.recipe_id','>=','1')
                            ->groupBy('recipe_list.recipe_id', 'recipe_list.recipe_name','recipe_list.recipe_desc','recipe_list.recipe_duration', 'recipe_cusine.Cusine_name','recipe_type.Recipe_type_name','recipe_list.image' )->get() ;
/*              var_dump($rec);
              die();*/
            return view('recipe', ['ingredients'=>$ing, 'cusine'=>$rcusine, 'type'=>$rtype,'recipe'=>$rec]); 


            }
```

the output i get is 
[image: The table output]

and this is my likerecipes table
[image: likerecipes table]

can anyone help me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the joins, your data is duplicated through the records. Since the `likerecipes` table seems to store like votes casted one by one identified by an `id` field uniquely, I would count the distinct `likerecipes.id` values per group:

```
'count(distinct likerecipes.id) as likes'
```

I would also introduce the `distinct` to the `group_concat()` to make sure that multiple like votes do not make the same ingridients appear multiple times:

```
'group_concat(distinct ing_list.Ing_name separator ",") as recipe_ingredients'
```

Comment: thankyou. It solved my problem but is there anyway to list recipes that do not even have single likes? the way it is now it only gives the list of recipes that has atleast one like count

Comment: Check out the outer joins (left and right joins). Btw, if you have a follow up question, then pls ask it in its own question, not as a comment in an existing question.